# Remove class of inner element on hovering outer div

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I'm wondering how can I hover some div and remove blur effect for the paragraph tag only in the div I'm hovering. Is there any other way except using id for the div and for the paragraph, cause i have something like 100 divs.

This is sample code:

```js
$( "div" ).hover(function() {
  $( "p" ).toggleClass( "clear" );
});
```

```css
  div {
    margin: 4px;
    font-size: 16px;
    font-weight: bolder;
    cursor: pointer;
 text-align: center;
  }
  .blue {
    color: blue;
  }
  .clear {
    background: yellow;
  -webkit-filter: blur(0px); /* Safari 6.0 - 9.0 */
    filter: blur(0px);
 -webkit-transition: ease-in 0.25s; /* For Safari 3.1 to 6.0 */
    transition: ease-in 0.25s;
 -webkit-transition: ease-out 0.25s; /* For Safari 3.1 to 6.0 */
    transition: ease-out 0.25s;
 cursor: pointer;
  }
  .diva {
 background: yellow
  }
  p {
   -webkit-filter: blur(1px); /* Safari 6.0 - 9.0 */
    filter: blur(1px);
 -webkit-transition: ease-in 0.25s; /* For Safari 3.1 to 6.0 */
    transition: ease-in 0.25s;
 -webkit-transition: ease-out 0.25s; /* For Safari 3.1 to 6.0 */
    transition: ease-out 0.25s;
 cursor: pointer;
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="blue"><p>paragraphs</p></div>
<div class="blue"><p>paragraphs</p></div>
<div class="blue"><p>paragraphs</p></div>
<div class="blue"><p>paragraphs</p></div>
<div class="blue"><p>paragraphs</p></div>
```

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use pseudo class `:hover`. Try:

```css
div {
    margin: 4px;
    font-size: 16px;
    font-weight: bolder;
    cursor: pointer;
 text-align: center;
  }
  .blue {
    color: blue;
  }
  div:hover p{
    background: yellow;
  -webkit-filter: blur(0px); /* Safari 6.0 - 9.0 */
    filter: blur(0px);
 -webkit-transition: ease-in 0.25s; /* For Safari 3.1 to 6.0 */
    transition: ease-in 0.25s;
 -webkit-transition: ease-out 0.25s; /* For Safari 3.1 to 6.0 */
    transition: ease-out 0.25s;
 cursor: pointer;
  }
  .diva {
 background: yellow
  }
  p {
   -webkit-filter: blur(1px); /* Safari 6.0 - 9.0 */
    filter: blur(1px);
 -webkit-transition: ease-in 0.25s; /* For Safari 3.1 to 6.0 */
    transition: ease-in 0.25s;
 -webkit-transition: ease-out 0.25s; /* For Safari 3.1 to 6.0 */
    transition: ease-out 0.25s;
 cursor: pointer;
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="blue"><p>paragraphs</p></div>
<div class="blue"><p>paragraphs</p></div>
<div class="blue"><p>paragraphs</p></div>
<div class="blue"><p>paragraphs</p></div>
<div class="blue"><p>paragraphs</p></div>
```

Comment: Great but what if i have another div instead of paragraph tag? Thats why i suppose that need some jQuery or JS.

Comment: @jonkata1985 then use selector `div:hover div` or add some class `div:hover .someclass`.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="blue"><p>A man </p></div>
<div class="blue"><p>A man </p></div>
<div class="blue"><p>A man </p></div>
<div class="blue"><p>A man </p></div>
<div class="blue"><p>A man </p></div>

<script>

    $( ".blue" ).hover(function() {
      $(this).find('p').css('filter', 'blur(1px)');
    }, function(){

        $(this).find('p').css('filter','');
        }
    );
    
    </script>
```

Comment: Gettin your point - added class 'blur' to to the paragraph but nothing happened at all. maybe i'm doing something wrong?

Comment: Sorry for delayed response. I just modified it, you can achieve this with just css too.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you need:

**using jQuery:**

```
$(function() {
    $("div").on('mouseenter',function() {
        $("div").not(this).find("p").removeClass("clear");
        $(this).find("p").addClass("clear");
    });
});
```

or **using CSS:**

```
div:hover p {
    filter: blur(0px) !important;
}
```